# javascript open.window function in same page bugging

Tags: javascript

I use a Javascript code to open a link in new tab when a button is clicked. I use this button:

```
<button  onclick="myFunction()">Link1</button>
<script>
function myFunction(){
  window.open("Link1");
}
</script>
```

And in another post in the home page of my blog, I put another button:

```
<button  onclick="myFunction()">Link2</button>
<script>
function myFunction(){
  window.open("Link2");
}
</script>
```

The problem is, when I click the button to go to Link1, it opens Link2.

How can I put my buttons all in home page without having this bug?

Thank you,

Comment: you have to make function names unique whitin a page. like `myFunction1` and `myFunction2`

Answer (score 0):

Your functions have the same name, rename your second function to myFunction2():

```js
<button  onclick="myFunction2()">Link2</button>
<script>
function myFunction2(){
  window.open("Link2");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but even changing function names still the same probleme.

Answer (score 0):

Naming your functions differently will fix your problem. But if your buttons really do just open links in new tabs you are better off using an Anchor tag with `target="_blank"`

e.g.

```html
<a href="/link1" target="_blank">link1</a>
```

And if you need that to look like a button, you can just style it with CSS!